# How to render a bar chart based on a selection from dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create an interactive bar chart in d3.js. The data for this is a .csv file that stores all the runs for each BIB (that is, athlete). I have used [d3.group()](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-group) to group by BIB but I don't know how I can select the BIB in the dropdown menu so that the runs for this particular athlete will be displayed. I am new to d3.js, so I appreciate all inputs and help. Right now, the figure looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I am able to log the particular BIB in the console but I don't understand how I can go from here to render a chart for the selected BIB that only shows his runs. I guess I am fairly close

Here's the  index.html that stores all my code:

```js
const data = d3.range(20).map(i => ({
  BIB: Math.floor(i / 5) + 1,
  RATIO: -1 + Math.random() * 2,
  RUN: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][i % 5],
  NAME: ['RASTAD', 'SANDENGEN', 'NYBORG', 'ANDERSEN'][Math.floor(i / 5)]
}));

// 1. This is the DropDownMenu 
const dropdown = (selection, props) => {
  const {
    options,
    onOptionClicked
  } = props

  let select = selection.selectAll("select").data([null]);
  select.enter().append("select").merge(select)
    .on("change", function() {
      console.log(this.value)
    })

  let option = select.selectAll("option").data(options);
  option.enter().append("option")
    .merge(option)
    .attr("value", d => d)
    .text(d => d)
}

// 2. This is the SVG element
const height = 300
const width = 700
const margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 50
}
// 3. THis is where I define the margin convention
const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right
const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

let selectBib;
let onSelectBibClicked = BIB => {
  selectBib = BIB;
  render();
}

// 4. This is the render function that creates the bar chart
const render = () => {

  d3.select("body").call(dropdown, {
    options: groupBySkiers,
    onOptionClicked: onSelectBibClicked,
  });

  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-3, 3])
    .range([innerHeight, 0]);

  const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(d => d.RUN))
    .range([0, innerWidth])
    .padding(0.1)


  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
  const xAxis = d3.axisTop(xScale)

  const g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)

  g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr('v', d => d.RATIO)
    .attr("x", d => xScale(d.RUN))
    .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", d => d.RATIO < 0 ? yScale(d.RATIO) - yScale(0) : yScale(0) - yScale(d.RATIO))
    .attr("y", d => d.RATIO < 0 ? yScale(0) : yScale(d.RATIO))
    .attr("fill", d => d.RATIO < 0 ? '#2ec1ac' : 'red')
    .append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.RATIO
    })

  yAxis(g.append("g").attr("class", "axis"))
  xAxis(g.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform", `translate(0,${yScale(-3)})`))

}

groupBySkiers = d3.group(data, d => d.BIB)
render()
```

```css
label {
  font-size: larger;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#startnummer {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: larger;
}

.axis {
  font-size: larger;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

rect:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<label for="bibnumber">Startnummer :</label>

<select name="STARTNUMMER" id="startnummer">
  <option value="volvo">1</option>
</select>
```

The original .csv file can be downloaded from [here](http://www.cmagelssen.no/index.csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a couple of improvements to your chart.
Firstly, I gave the dropdown better labels and changed the value to be the BIB of each athlete.

I also split the code into a `render` and an `update` function, so the one-time only code can be split off from the regular code.

You don't need `d3.group`, because you don't require the values, only the unique BIB numbers. So you can just change this to use an ES6 Set, an object, or a unique function like this:

```js
// This works because `indexOf` returns the first match.
// Any other matches have a different index `i` than the first match
const uniqueValues = arrayWithDuplicates.filter((d, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(d) === i));
```

Finally, there is no need to store a `selectBib` variable, if you only use it once. It's only necessary if you ever want to look up the value in a process that is not triggered by a dropdown change.

```js
const data = d3.range(20).map(i => ({
  BIB: Math.floor(i / 5) + 1,
  RATIO: -1 + Math.random() * 2,
  RUN: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][i % 5],
  NAME: ['RASTAD', 'SANDENGEN', 'NYBORG', 'ANDERSEN'][Math.floor(i / 5)]
}));

// 1. This is the DropDownMenu 
const dropdown = (options) => {
  let select = d3.select('select')
    .on("change", function() {
      const bib = Number(d3.select(this).property('value'));
      update(bib)
    })

  let option = select.selectAll("option").data(Object.entries(options));
  option.enter()
    .append("option")
    .merge(option)
    .attr("value", ([bib, name]) => bib)
    .text(([bib, name]) => `${bib} (${name})`)
}

// 2. This is the SVG element
const height = 300
const width = 700
const margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 50
}
// 3. THis is where I define the margin convention
const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right
const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom

let g, xScale, yScale

// 4. This is the render function that creates the bar chart
const render = () => {
  const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

  dropdown(uniqueSkiers);

  yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-3, 3])
    .range([innerHeight, 0]);

  xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(d => d.RUN))
    .range([0, innerWidth])
    .padding(0.1)

  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
  const xAxis = d3.axisTop(xScale)

  g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(yAxis)
  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${yScale(-3)})`)
    .call(xAxis)
  update(data[0].BIB)
}

const update = bib => {
  const filteredData = data.filter(d => d.BIB === bib);
  const rect = g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(filteredData, d => d.RUN);

  rect.exit().remove();
  rect
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .merge(rect)
    .attr('v', d => d.RATIO)
    .attr("x", d => xScale(d.RUN))
    .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", d => d.RATIO < 0 ? yScale(d.RATIO) - yScale(0) : yScale(0) - yScale(d.RATIO))
    .attr("y", d => d.RATIO < 0 ? yScale(0) : yScale(d.RATIO))
    .attr("fill", d => d.RATIO < 0 ? '#2ec1ac' : 'red')
    .append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.RATIO
    })
}

const uniqueSkiers = data.reduce((obj, {
  BIB,
  NAME
}) => {
  obj[BIB] = NAME;
  return obj;
}, {});

render()
```

```css
label {
  font-size: larger;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#startnummer {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: larger;
}

.axis {
  font-size: larger;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

rect:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<label for="bibnumber">Startnummer :</label>

<select name="STARTNUMMER" id="startnummer">
  <option value="volvo">1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you Ruben! Wouldn't it have worked with d3.group(). I thought that was the most natural way to do it? I need to some time to digest the code but it worked!

Comment: Look at the edit history, the previous version worked with `d3.group()`. It's just more complex than is necessary

Comment: I understand the code when you used random numbers, but I am struggling to add the d3.csv() into the function again. Should I wrap const uniqueskiers inside the the d3.csv() function so that it has access to the data?

Comment: Yes, I'd do `d3.csv().then(data => { data.forEach(d => d.BIB = +d.BIB); return data; }).then(data => { uniqueSkiers = ...; render(); })`